# PowerVR SDK drawing 3d model when an event occurs in android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, powervr-sgx

I am trying to create an application which will be using the camera to scan certain pictures and when a known picture is detected, it will draw a 3d model using powervr on top of the detected image.

Answer (score 1):

This page http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks also contains a lot of AR frameworks (maybe too much).

- METAIO - http://www.metaio.com
- Vuforia -
  https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality
- WIKITUDE SDK - http://developer.wikitude.com/documentation/android

Answer (score 0):

Dont have knowledge about this powervr-sgx
 There other Sdk available for Augmented reality pls follow this Url:http://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tutorials/hello-world/

This SDK provides the No of tutorial one specifically as your need detecting a specific picture and displaying the 3D object.

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you need a the Src contact me

Comment: I am using vuforia to detect the image and after detection i need to use the powervr native code to draw the 3d model. i have the two parts working independantly and even simultaneously.. i need a way to call android_main(android_app* state) of the powervr native code manually once vuforia detects an image